# From the list items, navigate to specific widget from json value in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to navigate to specific widget from the list of persons that I have defined in a `json` file. My `json` tree looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Abraham",
    "widget": "AbrahamWidget"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ross",
    "widget": "RossWidget",
  },
]
```

When I tap on any of the names, I handle the navigation with `onTap` to navigate to the `SearchResultNameWidget` where I check where to go with an `if` statement.

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SearchResultNameWidget(data[index]),
    ));
},
```

My `SearchResultNameWidget` is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nameapp/persons/abraham.dart';
import 'package:nameapp/persons/ross.dart';

class SearchResultNameWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    SearchResultNameWidget(this.data);
    final data;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        _person() {
            if (data["name"] == "Abraham") {
                return AbrahamWidget();
            } else if (data["name"] == "Ross") {
                return RossWidget();
            }
        }
        return _person();
    }
}
```

It works fine and navigate to the specific widget of a person from the list. But is there a better way to do this? If I had a lost of persons, defining if statements for each of them is very inconvenient. Can I bring the `widget` value from the `json` to programatically navigate to the specific widget of that person?

Comment: Why don't you have a generic Person View that accepts the data you get from the JSON?

Comment: @JoãoSoares, thanks but as per the requirement, different person may have different widgets. So do you think generic Person View would be helpful in that regard?

Comment: @Hijibiji I think this is not the real problem. The real problem is that that led you to the decision of creating a widget for each type of user. You need to reconsider your approach, if possible, open another question for help. There should be a way to minimize the number of widgets required.

Comment: Essentially what @bentesha said. What makes each Person's Widget so different from each other, that makes you fell like you need to make fully customised widget for each?

Comment: I feel that you may not yet grasp very well how Widgets work, or even classes. Can you please explain you are trying to achieve specifically? It's usually a good idea to explain what you want to do instead of saying how you want to do it and expect people to fix it.

Comment: Despite having set a bounty, it's been 3 days since you've replied to comments, or the answers provided. Please consider testing the answers and seeing if they fir your purpose. Otherwise there's no point using the bounty system.

Comment: @Hijibiji Does your issue resolved?

Comment: @JoãoSoares, sorry, I had been very ill since I've left the question. I think your approach for creating dynamic view is the best possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: I hope you get well soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have shared, it seems that you need to have a dynamic view based on the data received from JSON. The following code emulates this:

```
const String fakeJson =
  '[{"name" : "Lorena Hickle","user_name" : "Lee.Hand","user_id" : "Abel.Carroll@hotmail.com"},'
  '{"name" : "Archibald Johnston","user_name" : "Curt82","user_id" : "Unique_Kihn@hotmail.com"},'
  '{"name" : "Aida Rippin","user_name" : "Rebecca.Von","user_id" : "Marina.Terry94@yahoo.com"}'
']';

class Issue66740819 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Issue66740819State createState() => _Issue66740819State();
}

class _Issue66740819State extends State<Issue66740819> {
  List<Person> users = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    List jsonList = jsonDecode(fakeJson);
    loadUsers(jsonList);

    super.initState();
  }

  void loadUsers(List jsonList){
    setState(() {
      users = jsonList.map((user) => Person(
        name: user['name'],
        username: user['user_name'],
        userId: user['user_id']
      )).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: users.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(users[index].name),
          subtitle: Text(users[index].username),
          onTap: () => goToPersonView(users[index]),
        );
      }
    );
  }

  void goToPersonView(Person person){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
      return PersonView(person: person);
    }));
  }
}

class PersonView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Person person;

  const PersonView({Key key,
    @required this.person,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Person View'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Name: ${person.name}'),
            Text('Username: ${person.username}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  String name;
  String username;
  String userId;

  Person({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.username,
    @required this.userId,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a generic person widget's based on the type (which I assume would be less than 3 or 4).

for example, let's say person A is an admin and has a certain property and person B is a User and has some different property so you can create 2 types of person widget (Admin and user) and determine which type of person he is (you might have to add an extra field to identify the type) and pass the data in the widget.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Abraham",
    "widget": "AbrahamWidget",
    "data":{"Name":"Abraham",...} //user data
    "type":"Admin"

  },
  {
    "name": "Ross",
    "widget": "RossWidget",
    "type": "User",
    "data":{"Name":"Ross",...}

  },
]
```

```
if (data["type"]=="Admin")
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Admin(data:data["data"]),));
else
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => User(data:data["data"]),));
```

and in each type of widget, you can have properties specific to User or admin

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pushNamed`

like:

in main.dart

```
MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    '/AbrahamWidget': (context) => AbrahamWidget(),     
    '/RossWidget': (context) => RossWidget(),
  },
);
```

navigation part:

```
   onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/"+data[index]["name"]);
    },
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yet, if I had say 100 persons, I'd have to define routes for all 100 of them in the main.dart file. Is there any better way?

Comment: As i know, no more. At least, you need to pair you json and your class.

Comment: @Hijibiji intuitively, if your incoming data is unknown then you should not try to create specific classes/widgets for them. If you know how each user will be different from another then you should consider the answer of João Soares or Nishuthan S. Otherwise give us more context of your problem and maybe then we can provide an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can
**1.create a `routes.dart` file.**
eg:

```
const String abrahamWidget='/AbrahamWidget';
const String rossWidget='/RossWidget';
```

Then
**2.Create a router class**

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case abrahamWidget:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AbrahamWidget());
      case rossWidget:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RossWidget());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) =>
              Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                    child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
              ),
        );
    }
  }
```

**And in the `main.dart`**
This tells your app you are going to be working with these above defined routes.

```
return MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: startupPage,
  onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
);
```

**Finally**
You can call any of these routes by

```
   onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context,abrahamWidget);
            },
```

But you can skip this completely.
After looking at your code. I guess you are trying to:
•Search for a person and when user clicks on a item: Navigate to a new page display his details.

You can get this by a general page `user_details.dart`. And passing the user Values to this page.`UserDetails(this.data);` when an user taps on a Item and dsiplay different users.